# How can I manually edit gradients in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I'm writing a Keras implementation of DRLT (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08936), a Visual Tracker trained with Deep Reinforcement Learning, and I'm facing some troubles while trying to edit gradients and perform backpropagation.

To make it simple: I have an image as input, i compute features and make a prediction. What I need to do is get gradients and edit them according to equation (7) that you find in the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08936.pdf). I've noticed Keras' optimizers expose the `get_gradients` function but I haven't found any `apply_gradients` (that exists in TensorFlow). 
Here's my code, if you find it helpful.

```
predictions_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(self.T, self.N, 4))
rewards_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(self.T,self.N))

# Images ready to be used for training
for i in range(int(len(training_imgs) / self.T)):  # T frames at a time
    features = []
    hidden_states = []
    mu = []
    for j in range(self.T):
        print("Processing frame {}".format(i * self.T + j))
        # Compute {o_1 . . . o_T}
        features.append(self.extract_features(training_imgs[i * self.T + j], gt=y[i * self.T + j]))

        # Compute {h_1 . . . h_T}
        hidden_states.append(self.rnn.predict(features[j]))
        # Get mus
        mu.append(self.get_mu_from_hidden_states(hidden_states[j]))
        # loop over N episodes
        for e in range(self.N):
            # Randomly sample predictions for N episodes according to equation (8)
            #print('Episode: {}'.format(e))
            # Store predictions with corresponding rewards
            predictions_matrix[j, e] = self.sample_location(mu_t=np.squeeze(mu[j]),sigma=1e-2)
            if epoch < 300:
                rewards_matrix[j,e] = self.compute_early_reward(l_t=predictions_matrix[j,e],g_t=y[i * self.T + j])
            else:
                rewards_matrix[j, e] = self.compute_late_reward(l_t=predictions_matrix[j, e],
                                                                 g_t=y[i * self.T + j])
```

As you can see, I just can't use the `train_on_batch` method.
So, basically, I'm looking for a way of doing in Keras what it's done in TensorFlow with `apply gradients` or some tricks that could help me solve my problem.

Appreciate your help and if you need more info don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I think it is possible to run apply_gradients op using tensorflow session and set the same session to keras backend.